# What is the purpose of using cin.get() in a while loop?

Tags: c++

I don't understand why I have to use `cin.get()` again in while loop. Using `cin.get()` prior to the while loop does the same thing that `cin.get()` would do while also in the while loop. It reads a string of text I input while accounting for spaces. But obviously in this program I am trying to push all the text into a vector. If I were to exclude the `cin.get(next)` from the while loop and only have the `line.push_back(next)`, then the program gets an error and crashes.

Please explain why it does this. Thank you

```
//Demonstration of the generic find function
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
vector<char> line;
cout << "Enter a line of text: \n";
char next;
cin.get(next);
while(next != '\n')
{
    line.push_back(next);
    cin.get(next);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start by reading about [`std::basic_istream::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get). You won't understand what a program does if you don't understand the functions it calls. Related, your code has a bug. If by chance the stream incurs an error state it will loop to infinity looking for a newline that never comes.

Comment: It *get*s the input.  Not sure where the confusion is coming from.  Perhaps you should run the code through the debugger so you can see what it is actually doing.

Comment: You use it in a loop to get it to run many times. If you removed the line from the loop, all that'd loop would be pushing the same letter to the vector over and over again. Notice, that the end condition for the while loop would never come, if ever entered.

Answer (score 0):

Here´s a little guide to help you out. Sometimes it´s hard to see the forest for the trees at the beginning.

Define a variable named next of type char

```
char next;
```

Since next has no meaningful value right now, let´s get one. We need it for the condition in our while statement.

```
cin.get(next);
```

Lets loop around till next equals '\n'

```
while(next != '\n')
{
```

We still did not do anything meaningful with `next` the only thing we know is that it doesn´t equal '\n' so we really ought to do something with it.

We push it in our vector.

```
    line.push_back(next);
```

great. Done so far. We now need a new value for next for several reasons. On the one hand if we don´t change next we will loop forever (or too long at least) since the condition of the loop won´t get something new to chew on and on the other hand we want a new value for our vector, don´t we?

So yes, lets get the next next

```
    cin.get(next);
```

And back to the beginning of our loop for testing

```
}
```

that´s it.